# Mongoose, Node.js get sum of a field from a bunch of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose method/query which finds all 'incomes' from a certain user but only if the dates of the 'incomes' are within the current month.

Code:

```
module.exports.getMonthlyIncome = function(userId, callback){
const now = new Date();

const year = now.getFullYear();
const month = now.getMonth();
const date = now.getDate();

const start = new Date(year, month, 1);
const end = new Date(year, month, 30);

Income.find({owner: userId, date: { $gte: start, $lt: end }}, callback);
}
```

Result:

```
[
{

"_id": "58cc9ee50fe27e0d2ced5193",
"amount": 600,
"description": "Ripco Salary",
"owner": "58cc9e950fe27e0d2ced5192",
"__v": 0,
"date": "2017-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"
},

{

"_id": "58ccc3cfca6ea10980480d42",
"amount": 450,
"description": "Another Ripped co salary",
"owner": "58cc9e950fe27e0d2ced5192",
"__v": 0,
"date": "2017-03-26T00:00:00.000Z"
}

]
```

Result is as expected, gives me the 2 income documents belonging to a certain user during the month.

Now, I want to get the total sum of every 'amount' field from these documents.

So in this case, the sum would be 1050.

How would I achieve this in Mongoose?

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [mongoose Aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to calculate the sum of `amount` across multiple document.

you need to use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match), to match the query condition, [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) to calculate sum across multiple documents.

```
Income.aggregate([{
    $match : { $and : [ {owner: userId}, {date: { $gte: start, $lt: end } }] },
},{
    $group : {
        _id : null,
        total : {
            $sum : "$amount"
        }
    }
}],callback);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is litlle mistake in your code:  $match : { $and : [ {owner: userId, date: { $gte: start, $lt: end } }] },

Comment: @krekto thanks, I updated it. Didn't see that mistake at all

Comment: is the `$and` needed? multiple conditions are per default `and` expressions, no?
so `$match : { owner: userId, date: { $gte: start, $lt: end } }` should work just the same, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this.

**1. Using aggregation queries:** 
Looks like you are new to mongodb. So, I would not suggest this approach for you. This approach is correctly covered in another answer and that should work totally fine. Do check it out!

**2. Using [underscore-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore-node):**

Rewriting your code:

```
module.exports.getMonthlyIncome = function(userId, callback){
const now = new Date();

const year = now.getFullYear();
const month = now.getMonth();
const date = now.getDate();

const start = new Date(year, month, 1);
const end = new Date(year, month, 30);
// Including underscore-node
const _ = require('underscore-node');
Income.find({owner: userId, date: { $gte: start, $lt: end }}, function(err, results){
   if (err) {
    //handle error
   }

   let sum = _.reduce(results, function(memo, reading){ return memo + reading.amount; }, 0);
   // Explaination:
   // reduce() accepts an array and a callback function.
   // So, we are passing the array in "results"
   // In the callback function, do not touch "memo" variable
   // Every single object in "results" array will be passed 
   // to callback function in the "reading" variable
});
```

Hope this code helps you!

Comment: you could also use the native array.reduce function